# How to Store a Windows.UI.Color Object in a SQLite Database?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, colors, windows-store-apps

Iam using a `SQLite Datatabase` to store the Data of my `Windows 8 Store App` developed in `C# and XAML`.

And now Iam looking for an easy way to store a `Color` Object that should be used as a XAML `Color` (**Windows.UI.Color**) in this Database.
So I think i have to **Convert the `Color` Object to a string or an integer** in that case!?

I can Convert the `Color` with the `ToString()` method to a string representation but how can it i convert it back?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.color.fromargb.aspx

Answer (score 2):

A solution to this would be to store the ARGB byte values in the database and then you can use the `Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b)` method to get the color from those stored byte values.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.color.fromargb

Answer (score 2):

I am trying with my following answer to help you out.

1. Assume you wish to store the ColorObject.ToString() value e.g. #659EBCF5
2. Feel free to save it in SqLite as varchar aka string.
3. When you need it back, read from SqLite and store it to a variable say colorString.

Assuming colorString  = "#659EBCF5";

...

```
colorString = colorString.Substring(1, colorString.Length - 1);//remove the #
        System.Globalization.NumberStyles style = System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber;
        int hexColorAsInteger = int.Parse(colorString , style);
        byte[] colorData = BitConverter.GetBytes(hexColorAsInteger);

        //Mind the order.
        byte alpha = colorData[3];
        byte red = colorData[2];
        byte green = colorData[1];
        byte blue = colorData[0];

        Color color = Color.FromArgb(alpha, red, green, blue);
```

Comment: Realized that in any hex string after # e.g. "#659EBCF5" 65 is alpha, 9E is red, BC is green and F5 is blue in Hexadecimal. So a little less parsing is required and you just need to convert these hex values to decimal and can easily construct the color. :)